# Filtering a dataframe based on a value from column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dataset

I have a dataframe df as shown below

```
 sample  variant            
1 HLA1    1,3,4,5            
2 HLA2    1,5 
3 HLA3    2,3
4 HLA4 
5 HLA5    1
6 HLA6    1,4,3
7 HLA7    1
8 HLA8    4,3
```

I would like to extract all the rows with "1". For eg This is the Output I need

```
 sample  variant            
1 HLA1    1,3,4,5            
2 HLA2    1,5 
3 HLA5    1
4 HLA6    1,4,3
5 HLA7    1
```

So i thought this would work

```
CF <- df[df$variant=="1"]
```

And this gave me as follows

```
 sample  variant 
1 HLA5    1
2 HLA7    1
```

Can anyone help to achieve this in R. I have simplified my case here, actuality the dataframe runs to over a hundred thousand rows. Thank you

Comment: df[grepl("1", df$variant ), ]

Comment: Thank you..this worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the class of `df$variant` is `'character'`.

You can then use `df[grepl('1',df$variant),]`